# input type=submit not following box-model

Tags: html, theory, css

I have more of theoretic question: do you know why in the world, `input type=submit` acts on different box-model **even if I tell it do `display:block`**?

(just a note: nothing I couldn't go around... It just surprised me, that this time, every browser seems to work the same way… padding and border *included* in total `width`

second note: i see no point in `quirks mode`, never used it (seems to me from far ago, that it just f*cks everything up—more than usual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never closely researched this, I just know buttons never do what they're told.

Is this what you mean? [**Explorer Windows and Mozilla bug - button box model**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tests/mozie_button.html)

There is a Fix for Mozilla:

> For Mozilla, add -moz-box-sizing: content-box to the button. Unfortunately this bug is unsolvable in Explorer.

Comment: I don't actually think you can call it *bug* - **every** browser (I actually test in latest FF, Op, Safari, Chrome and IE6/7/8) works the same... maybe there is some historical reason to it? as for - *buttons never do what they're told* - don't let me even start there :D

Comment: It's most likely a limitation of whatever operating system you're using, which would explain the consistent results.